# How do mediafiles look? (Please read first)

Tags: android, file, media, drawable, xmp

I am having a huge error with playing media files. This [Media file in wrong encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657608/media-file-in-wrong-encoding) shows the problem I am having. My media player file looks very weird and that may be why my app is not working. 
For android studio is the media file suposed to have a playbutton or code because when I open up my media file it shows this:

```
ID3    CTYER      2016 TDAT      1401 TIME      1419 PRIV  W  XMP 

<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c111 79.158325, 2015/09/10-01:10:20        ">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
    xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
    xmlns:stEvt="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceEvent#"
    xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#"
    xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
    xmlns:creatorAtom="http://ns.adobe.com/creatorAtom/1.0/"
    xmlns:xmpDM="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/1.0/DynamicMedia/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmpMM:InstanceID="xmp.iid:4f8bdd82-b23d-47f0-a030-79c78178f88e"
   xmpMM:DocumentID="c165b52d-e9ca-0ec6-e406-ebf300000047"
   xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID="xmp.did:54c715de-270a-4ec2-bfde-7e5d39a048b3"
   xmp:MetadataDate="2016-01-14T14:19:34-08:00"
   xmp:ModifyDate="2016-01-14T14:19:34-08:00"
   xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC (Macintosh)"
   xmp:CreateDate="2016-01-14T14:19:04-08:00"
   xmpDM:audioSampleRate="-1"
   xmpDM:audioSampleType="16Int"
   xmpDM:audioChannelType="Stereo"
   xmpDM:startTimeScale="30000"
   xmpDM:startTimeSampleSize="1001"
   dc:format="MP3">
   <xmpMM:History>
    <rdf:Seq>
     <rdf:li
      stEvt:action="saved"
      stEvt:instanceID="abdb65d6-add1-4884-ae3a-53b600000074"
      stEvt:when="2016-01-14T14:19:34-08:00"
      stEvt:softwareAgent="Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC (Macintosh)"
      stEvt:changed="/"/>
     <rdf:li
      stEvt:action="created"
      stEvt:instanceID="xmp.iid:80538dc7-efe5-4e6d-8702-e2a00e50f759"
      stEvt:when="2016-01-14T14:18-08:00"
      stEvt:softwareAgent="Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC (Macintosh)"/>
     <rdf:li
      stEvt:action="saved"
      stEvt:instanceID="xmp.iid:9a7174b0-cbaa-4e93-aa3a-3cefb9771883"
      stEvt:when="2016-01-14T14:19:34-08:00"
      stEvt:softwareAgent="Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC (Macintosh)"
      stEvt:changed="/"/>
     <rdf:li
      stEvt:action="saved"
      stEvt:instanceID="xmp.iid:4f8bdd82-b23d-47f0-a030-79c78178f88e"
      stEvt:when="2016-01-14T14:19:34-08:00"
      stEvt:softwareAgent="Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC (Macintosh)"
      stEvt:changed="/metadata"/>
    </rdf:Seq>
   </xmpMM:History>
   <xmpMM:Ingredients>
    <rdf:Bag>
     <rdf:li
      stRef:instanceID="a5bea526-6192-792c-f200-1d630000006a"
      stRef:documentID="0a5d55a5-cbaa-e20b-9f5a-1d3f0000003d"
      stRef:fromPart="time:14222169561600f254016000000d339026688000f254016000000"
      stRef:toPart="time:0d339026688000f254016000000"
      stRef:filePath="00002.MTS"
      stRef:maskMarkers="None"/>
    </rdf:Bag>
   </xmpMM:Ingredients>
   <xmpMM:Pantry>
    <rdf:Bag>
     <rdf:li>
      <rdf:Description
       xmpMM:InstanceID="a5bea526-6192-792c-f200-1d630000006a"
       xmpMM:DocumentID="0a5d55a5-cbaa-e20b-9f5a-1d3f0000003d"
       xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID="xmp.did:e0079809-312a-4e7d-a92d-84f92a113400"
       xmp:MetadataDate="2016-01-14T14:18-08:00"
       xmp:ModifyDate="2016-01-14T14:18-08:00">
      <xmpMM:History>
       <rdf:Seq>
        <rdf:li
         stEvt:action="saved"
         stEvt:instanceID="a5bea526-6192-792c-f200-1d630000006a"
         stEvt:when="2016-01-14T14:18-08:00"
         stEvt:softwareAgent="Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC (Macintosh)"
         stEvt:changed="/"/>
       </rdf:Seq>
      </xmpMM:History>
      </rdf:Description>
     </rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
   </xmpMM:Pantry>
   <xmpMM:DerivedFrom
    stRef:instanceID="xmp.iid:80538dc7-efe5-4e6d-8702-e2a00e50f759"
    stRef:documentID="xmp.did:80538dc7-efe5-4e6d-8702-e2a00e50f759"
    stRef:originalDocumentID="xmp.did:80538dc7-efe5-4e6d-8702-e2a00e50f759"/>
   <creatorAtom:windowsAtom
    creatorAtom:extension=".prproj"
    creatorAtom:invocationFlags="/L"/>
   <creatorAtom:macAtom
    creatorAtom:applicationCode="1347449455"
    creatorAtom:invocationAppleEvent="1129468018"
    creatorAtom:posixProjectPath="/Volumes/Justine/BAND/Vocabulary Audio Assets/Miwok Vocab Audio.prproj"/>
   <xmpDM:projectRef
    xmpDM:type="movie"/>
   <xmpDM:duration
    xmpDM:value="40"
    xmpDM:scale="1001/30000"/>
   <xmpDM:startTimecode
    xmpDM:timeFormat="2997DropTimecode"
    xmpDM:timeValue="00;00;00;00"/>
   <xmpDM:altTimecode
    xmpDM:timeValue="00;00;00;00"
    xmpDM:timeFormat="2997DropTimecode"/>
  </rdf:Description>
 </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>





















<?xpacket end="w"?>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ���@  ��A�BCJ���=�HE$c��� ��cp�� ����&��U8]�#�q��,�#��W=rd��`�������G���)�)�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Q�[*�.摈ϸ���L�w���2\C�0�g��T�^���?�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������$�I4�  �9+{�ì^~s�kAQ`�����F�FZi�i$�i  h�����/?9ε����0z�x����M��-4�  ���@  � Fc/z@���e�Hx��a�A���=hm��m]* t�br̽Ŝ ]�x� ���5غ~bFO�ޏD?Q�� ��/���:!7�5b�)���ըvQ�xw��]���*�+j����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������M��@���N@����� �����B��H���肧�5�c$���c��Ps�D&�ƬX�=>���;O N���� �\P�mB����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������m��w" <*z�ɠ,��
��?L�
�KR�=�v4X�X4-�"�a4��ɲ_wb!*@��C�d�����U�1}I�+��z�������޲Z�imB��B��� Oٴ���
��Q܈ �U�&���h4��3d+a-JLd�h1��   `#I`ж8�%���_&�}݈���O�u��b�+O�V|��'�x�r�������;�wz�k���opm�[T"؁?f�J�D���@  �=F�j��Ǩ�c-\����  J���a)-�܎7%D]D�u���ۮP�?3dƚT���@�rOr �Qx�u��{�C��U ÏK`i
Z W�X�b�I��E�<��`
�J���[��ֺ+Z(u���dt�t.(4�(R��Kz�96�]��7���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������n7#��ID��Qr]A�C2��8O�� ���� �aP���Ŝ�5�^%s�����w�@0���CV����'��bbQtO$�tR�dV벵��֊}o�_�4��
-�T�tR���M�W{������������������e�;I"��x����>�   �Dr���Ŕ�QT&�(BU���
�J�f�j�f�4g�+���j���:�+,) �p�2�l=*��V��^��%�+�5zQ5���Z�h�����6���yɷJ�
��������,�[#���(Xǋ�� ��I��G(p�J��YIBh�%P��� �t��h���m�Fz��x��*����b�    g�*��Ҫj{�o)�[�R_��PW�[k������8�ch�n眛t��1q0�n����������@  �AE�Z���(�c\��!�a�j�d5�=-&�Mܢ�l_��Y�����d�E�p�UU�G�0�i�L������Ğ�<9]����?����۩T��p"Y4�>�a)�es�Ly�!�dS��~���~ȓ�{�&%�U�9̲����&4*\p& �
��1�Rj��Vy�vF�W�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������q6�n�b�$� ��wf@�K$�(,�������b8���L�dLE%ֶ$��I���5��GFPv�J���v�;�ɤ��  N;+���c��
�"��s�_���D�c�Q1-ꭈ��e��}M$�1�R��X�0(��U�1�r�U�Z��#�4���L�kn�4H ����@�� � 0�-Y�0�H�Z40��e:e �����f��~l�2K2�k)L�@$�&
�+
5�HZ����%��K�:��H7(��c�ic)V��`{c1
D��3�2��d����x�)�vc�
ٖmm�F� ��4�(X@y  ^��8�ikF��̧L����p�o͛�If]S-e)�����d�W�aF��Q�^>7�3�I~S^i���y-,e#j��lf#AH��FsU��,�6��/=��x����@  
�RG�9`�JH�g#lɃ�`m0b�
�1�%�H�m6D2�:b¦�<$��� ���_����I4��F'�$c������rE�?�u$nDۨ��\xf��MjA�����Sf2h�AI�~R��dm�#&p4�i�p�B�~_�M�S��ɐ�ц��|�E�   ���Y�?���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������j�n�6�M�����p���   <# �H'/2��>�RM ���  ��E���8�7�E��]I�6�<2��{�Z�cn���F���ٌ��8�PRz_���Yh�ɜ
!��/Я���E�yC���2d ta�.>�q�E�!'���~��I�J��Ⲃ�
��z�)�
T�!r.�*�^��e��܍�ԥbx�����tY�~�H6����zNn�x�ζ�S��D���
�c¢c*n ;.�� ��da,OE6ÌEY�f$�x����v�6V̟wXm�-���ag�R ��E�]G�������$�i�R��8����F(��^���C�U.�\��
��׭z�r���7#s5)X�7��]z�
�$-/f�����5�������Q:�2r7��ʛ�˲1� *K�M��A�uق   �-'a(�ݢ͕�'��rG���Y���<6�uQ�q}���;�*}����@  
�^GkK`�+��a�l��a�0����=�.I$�8�m�z��.O�Vg����O��>�ܦ�oXB���"��K�Q�w8�U�%�c�3��q<c�-�6������D�6�!A�l'���Gs`���*�A$ ���6Q�
�kE�N��u����S��Τ�e(��}��JG��5�r>;��f<���pɊ��?��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������rI$���m#��!p|�<�/}G����6X�z��=fafbX�:�s��X®p�,���m����$��H

�`�<=;�͜�aT�� Me����n[Z(Ԫt'8�����x�Z���u$�)G�+�R>a������k0����nW��LU�Y��7-�Y#i�Zz�dI*�m
���J�ٗ��P̟5�R)���$Eʍ++z�LY9X #�F���5g� `�Ԏ3[({gIڍ9�h�a���g
HB��9Oc��t�bssP����KS�1�x����c-6�B��?Ѩtd6!ԝ�:���hQ�>���{�+�W�h�Ɲ�3I��"+qX����~bcv�����Zfԥ)Z1Z�>����,���t�=K�$�a��N`R�m����F�S(fO��W��Yl�"�F���G�,���#XD^���� 0W�G��=���F�ʴJ0�~t���!Bf��ĉP�J�9��U���%�Ø�<I��v�1��_�WE��:2�NÊ�x�s4(�VXӽ�
֕����i�N���H��ZQ��?11�h���ǭ3jR���H��_����@  
�_F�/3`���e�l)��=
�0c
���UR��\5��e%�$�9#�"n������
�:� �|��l/��v�u�m�RZ��mY>Rf���%�o�?��:�ԍ>SBW�3N���sfJ�'�V�QU��{��Eȗǲg��Ws����a�#��;wP�k�>��K`�$?�}  �������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������q���U/��Y�LR^"Kc� b<�&���~
�
P�S�БN*��yv��m�YV�U%����%��&h�lRZV���O�����-H��4%p��4�=�6d�ar5m%X� ��D\�|{&{��w0�:���:��u��s�\��q`q�
�C�GВݖJ�R��B��T�ٽ��!�<��A-�;�TQ=��z|ʭgmg{$u�j�qķyv� �k��7}����Ţ�ÇB����Q�ap��9�V��ۣ��y��*��(�"�F���  $�̓@�`�;s�QP�ؐ��V����\yc4�C{m��7�`�[����e��T��P�4%�oB#���lO2�f�Kq��OE%,��2�Y�Y��gڰ�q-�]�H-Z�or��f%�y�h�0�ТD8�rT{\)�Nb����f�6��u�`�ʇ6r�,��)�(� �I,3`�.�5��pTT:v$?@�U�<:�6WX�2�P�^Ǜc!M�X-�������@  �`G�3h���a�mM��=-�ɰc����-�$�uH
h�=Y��  LPiz�RWj̭�XB4BcR�A���8��$���i���y�b��dt8�pS� ��$p��
R ���� ����3,!̈́�8���tF�#���,��>��y �^�2z�,@��AUN�F�ՓQ9����h�*U-s_��߫����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������v�$�R�!Vb�G^���ڳ+fV�F�P�ԮPe9�D���)?I*�wZa�y�nX�ó�.�ꁀ)6I�g���#*��(-:5�sa3�4����kH��r�C4�O�|�H;�����K!{PB�S�ѹ�d�Ni,z>4ʕK\��kw��������h�v ����(c���.UHq�4  `������VrVƂ��ҡY,8�Y�T1zhv����yxq[��g]2��d�b
����rMӧ���<g@G�D
�ֈ*S;��]玽V�n�
#cbq    ���Z
)
IE����DÓ{r$�M�@�bA&���.�]�.�j�����?��BbB�]m�V���Eq�w[�ʩ:��,4yCj�J��[|�T+%�5j�/Mгw�/+|XL�Q�AS��y�I�t���'��h�bH�[:�Jg~"�K��ת� C�ѡB�llN!73�U�A��#"��(���"5ȘronD�)���H$��٥�����\w^T���@  �^��/Kh�k�e�m�}-�1-������%�]m�ID�:�W⢧�4�I�H�F*��"�?Ha�t���Z-��)�ٟ'�Nc=B�ǌ�S�P�*��Zhc����֑R�-`(��"ASqVe�L��Ѹ�֪�NŘ��T��a�ʹ+0��j\1�!QIHTB�})8���D��p@��~�gWQ�#%�V���ԯS�^����U?�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������K���#h��GX��TT�F�I"T   H�^��S��I0��RtkE�cم5;3��    �g�P��Jtj[�Msrq�Z�*PE�8DH*`N*��I�y7`��Q�)س��*�{Zl5��f�TmK�1d*))
�R#ϥ'Z`�Ȑ����7�Û���5$d��������bK����^""����%L^t�-�8�a�YS��י#I"q����T�b�&Pa}w���ۇ�������Ei�\��I&�H����"WG�%>�f��7    Hj,�u ���$Q���3 ��m�'f]��*��#�r����I"��d�
�)��3`��5[qmftю�Bm�/���l���&/:Z��w�h��,�փZ�̑��8�@ah�|�b(0���;�s`�m��p�`|�w~���.iB��|    $P����+�#���Q3H����
�W:�P�l�(�|�
���y�ѓ�.�j��i��9M
������  �o�D�R�E�a������:h�@�6����@  
D`L�    Kl� �a)m�9�9�%-��0'5���Y$�ұA �� ʺ3��kD��./i�\��H�'D~Zig��S�"Ȧ�D"h�O�s
R&�>Z8�i����{LE�
�
�L�$��Ԍ6O�(ٳH��flfН�k�U�Ša�Pٵ5�Q:ˢ�j�@!!e�2?IQ|aE%����U�~����)���[S�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������%�I'�+
"���:�F�JnB����ˋD��qG妐�x�0X,�hdB 6��,4�W0�"i#壈����
�w��Z!`����"JʭH�d����4�&f�fm    ئ�Y�ZU
�S^YaU��(&�tX�#�$���R[�*��X7�{�H�i)�3v�[l�6�a��$
=�/��.��Mm:]fRhptD`����j�Wӳey�� X�9ܢ;���b;�2UA�5�βO B�m�Q���Xdj4�4T?��*���Dd����>\R�Q(�D��pXФ�P����@��ZB"���ôX��
    ��`�JJvi��'�i�M��m�H�I�>0�(������Y5��u�I�����BN��\0wN͕狤�b8�cr��טi��PD�UP֗:�M<�
I��FLBa��@lҬ�P�@"H� .]�G�20�qJ5D����cB�uB�
�υ X
�Qi�G�NG�b� 4&&�A�Y))٤F(�VQ�"����@  �^Ly�Kj�Kɏ=)mV��1�=-�а&=������w}��K@2�:wbB��#��QyF�Q5�=����+3 )u��"P�Q�`l�̣'VM"��#z�Ҫis�d�TҌ��Э@����`�I��V=�����I6^�o֎����dJ�j�.PV�.eƒhЁ�_&�$F�5��m��W2�c��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Ţ!���}�����Νؐ��k��~�^Q��McOEeE&���v�����
]rq��T-{6�(�ՓH�fH�޳4��Z\��8�@U4�•4+EFP m&��+�m6�k�Fj{9M������p�t��Bڳ����@���4 G%WɯI���D�l�U̶X�!x��������0�� ���W�\�e�I�|m�a��r����BqX�S2Ǣ�h����@�ͥ����jT!�Y*3k�&iI�@g�)I�w�6�.��fD��rs@���eN>�<:�2��g�.����iw,��;2���� $8u�"V�v6>�����`I3tàx�$��
�MmDG���&��L������Jd�LR߫��V��Ծ6�0��9\L�t!8�\��c�r�4K���� Gf���aw5*କ��4���3��܌;ǛIWҳ"j�@9���m ���2�'}�@@j3ƗE��K4��Tq�DTLQ 
:�+b�QBF�q�R0$��a�<E
L҆�&��#��B`���@  �`�i�Kx�Lm=�o�}5��������=�}���m�:�i}p��s�jj2�f�>t�T0K��F�ͯ6)��d%2���Ɩ�8��R�}h��
 ���\�����n�u�����=Ą�Q��3C���%|�QY���H���@��@pR���O7��Sj-�^C)��<N����'�@    %]�i��C����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������m���m�8�Q��  �va�-���PY����P�/,>1�6�ئ~Ő��|n�Z��#=J�����4�^Cs�<�%��B~��0`�_�F��g�@��1Ef.f�"�ZRIF��H0CXn׍<�"�M��f�y��X�:d"�$J$�y $|�w�FU���m��=�H!�G1��rI��!�R�K��0&%��N�,�o��o�;���^�����[  ��H<��hZ��^Ά�a�Ȇ+
i��Z�~��2U�����[��P��w�uy�i���4���N+�yΧC�sM4Ѓ�@t85a�\�3L�.e��4�r��(5�ǭs��3�k����Ē�*%�ۭ�{\�C؎c-�]>C��r�P!`LK�R�jY�ߴ9��dw����?Q'@00�@&���yo4д=����?Ñ�V*�'j�=N���<d�~)��ö���;������.�h!!ȜV'��N���i�"��pj:Ð��f��\�y�i���P22028ku�Z�?�g��1}�Y�-�%�T���@  
�^���{h�ٝ=�m��#��-�1$u���/����l��+�i���Iԣ��lZ���Q:I�ܷ�V���D�}�x��О�^��T4��1A-�ϴ(�>ᙨ��<��x�f%U�5113(`@|�hѤ��bm�ƏHxbU*�|������fX����73�1XYXX\aN�fQ.�nC�^�a��J[X{WP5H��HV�l�qkf��cC�Z  ��j���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������ml��ۂ�V�K���J?Z�Ũϑ�%��
��y�kO4LA��w��(��   ����CNQm�l�B�#���:�ϟG�\�bU^S2��֍L^&!���h�%R����,��,�fe�Ho^�s=��������e�F�9��F������uT��ąk6��m��4:�ՠ@��|���cr$ILH3}F�&Mҽ�L���-uCH5q$�D2%�k��\�\Ϸ$�����[�h����j�� r�U+�f����(���hr-�������Frf,4LL��>�Ĩ�K��XI
���ق���!K�D�9R
E�@�ₑ��"$a"(YaQf�I}��C%�E7��
@�S/�(������cz)����m�ȑ%0 P��X�4sJ��2nʠ��
 �Ē�ȗU�K�Es=s>ܓ��c,n%���4�[K�%�yT�U�#�##��J�ǁ�ȶw��"�G�ɘ��12�h�S�,NW
`8y$*V�fDB4l�,�,�dpqH)'�
Ds30�����e�E�)%�BU�A޺�(I�yL�\�����~.�a�S�����@  
�`�kKx��Ma�o��-�1��0%��1�.]m��#i&N�<��+�V6lÙD9 w������p�*�����Rbe�CXH��!(�����\T�NvOBp��$GQ��5h�%l�q�HRu!L��Q�)H�Q�4H�qB�A�Z�I�Y2��"���٨4�hNy�뒊^qIM�؜'k'�y�!�E�5%"�$H   ����k/�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������u��$���8�+Ĭ)Xٳe����@�hg��������HM���i
a"�\������qRe9�=    ����F���u���<}�e�CI!Iԅ26�F$�#MD:��A"��
�Ek�&�dˣp�F�Of����9��J)y�%6�wbp���G$U�<�m�Ԕ�4� &�Ŭ��북Dhwww�kd�MÎ$zJ�8�/4G�N����i�=�GS�/��ҩ��@:�����~I.]����p��f��'k} ���DT\R��y�����K�����0z�I*J��H�,�%�B�xdbj|TD����^�Cڲ�J�V��F���M�EO�@TT�A�a��:�88�y}��Õ�)�y�O.���S[�O�5���������m��U78x��+���
d�;�s$ ���IO�fJ��� �����$�v�OӜ�SP=��T�����QqJ��lXp"�VG1.��0ӯtHT���$\�*�Y"��ȗ��ᑉ��Qs����{�jʬ0Q*�Z^%jU78=<_IQS������~}��jSV����<x��2�Mn]?T�c�����@  M`L�)ch�� �e,mɁ7�፲�0&�1�G�ww}��۔E7��R
+�u5�k���Ř&��9!��[v�@xQ �����&K�}hi!��O���:e���@/F���}(��6����i��V%AI��I˅�pi`���5�����xə�cIM�-�N�w��Ҥ�E1אKe��j��A"�D�P�
A�)�����6�F��0{����W������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������<;���ܢ)�w��i^�;\l]�,�4� ���*�[���Me�݆2]��CIf�}�V��,����z7�w K�Gu�f��L�J�(2
NWN\/+�KE�09�.5E��L�Jo-�l�t;�'��%z(Ɏ��Ț[,lkW�x� �'$:�PRiNNoE'W���b5�Q��l�f��rI$��������<��Q�# ɡ��"  �&�2��  ��p��e�=5!��Ea���8��<�۹QW���hm��i`�i0�O�����=_#�T����K��_,�
`ܶ���oD��|~��zB�*|�znZ�}�I�O�Ɔ���̟�>y�v�C��-rfc�q��?�?L�du��\�I'�+&� p�4O&5h���2hd&�rɺ̡pB`�\ A�&YB��MHnD�QXbb/�#~O=v�TU��sw�X3ZL&��78/�%ũ�W��#(6C���)��73��(A�7-�`���!��/ސ��
�%^����~Rt��������y5�'�O�f�������\����\f(��e�O��9B�����@  `Tkx{l�L
�om���Q�a��*5�=�%�v�[l�9 �������}�N�-2`�Ɔ ^�
���W���u����KJ��A�n8�]�k��5W,����x�0���ë�$�p�������Ho�c8�gZ3١,�a�}����">���6��?]��>^Ijی��¬ˀ�ȩ��ׇK���r�����Y�������m���K-������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������nݮ��+�@),`�i~a�F, ��L��1��ס���y����?��h~6�RҾ��{[�;k��/��U�.�7�$�0!����5\8��x9�%�6����/�֌�hK,�b_b<��H��{�y
����u�����C�ڶ������2�9�*e��u�ǒ���ܹ�~�7�k�>����_���b��R�[���$��\<؀~줫��{���vH"���*fL��^z͝��ۙ@xq�݉���� /���6q�v��,�l8c7�*�g�T��7�D���� �K�k�X�*'C`8J�B�<���^+�U5"<XW*K��HW�Uz:�Ζ��f�6��k�ά�mo���9y!�,�
w�1��ux�޾�[�
��8,��/|Q�6��ݶ��%������e%]�
+�f�L��A^GP�2g.2��l�.��Ì��M�w�' I'�Y���Đ@G$!g�a���V�<���Q�j$}�EB]#^2�]�Q:�T��<�l��^2���¹R_��@��"���&t�~P�4Q���\�ud3k}�����1`�xS���M.{�Ǝ��b�xm.��f�q{⌱�����@     �_Tk�n���cm�ՁQ�g
�:�*5�� )$��,�8�&H- �jL��'Vn%:mŜ�KSZt!P�a�g{��nQ��p����M֬��2�u�]飔��W{����^�QnN���̚N���k�)D9���dx8�ҩl�
xK7��Ύ��R#O��;�+�'E��� =S�ԭ݄��mFr��s;��:��\�w�L��7�c����k��T�s���d��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������,��㼙 �Xq�3�X�Y���pC�-MhaЅ@2�����M���FxBq��w�97Z�(w�Xʙ�J�w��R�%]�dvf7Ez5E��:R�32i;�+�����/�)����J���)�,�Z�::�H�>�h���ĝ��| �N�R�v/����������Ys��u3�0�5�w�3ݮ۱S��Xo/��`�I��[$�U@��,�f�����o]��À
�8զ)��'(?�ض7:D�/6��}����M�"Ó6�P�=�W%�z��%u`Y[�/{�����g)��/.�n   �,�����2�p�Q�H��z̺���f��j?����-
H��-�
� �uꕾ��$�<��v���<����3��<f�4��~�.xV�֫�K��,=0�vync.��O �Mm��%�� �f�35�L�N�z��� l�ƭ1M(v�9A�.ű���$�y�� �k��ݎvbm�������|r�-�׶�+���i{�%}�>#8�O�9yvCpN��f�,�?�3���Fg��e��h�S4��Q�����hjF���m�nYPïT���'!�ܣ��0���nW��&��6����)s´n�X�r_VQa���swjx���@  
(`Tk8cl��
�gm�yuY�c
�O.�5�a�@7#��$���QH|x��M�lP�6j�z�Z@��L\�r�����*�;bY>�Br�iӝ���IC��!��(   h���6K?*�I�I5�dŴ;R�a�H@�hm�}n#>�m�n��y��Be��V;[��^���M�U�S���
��~��c��ދ��I2�f��0aWQeY�Y��H�?f�5j�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������@7#��$���QH|x��M�lP�6j�z�Z@��L\�r�����*�;bY>�Br�iӝ���IC��!��(    h���6K?*�I�I5�dŴ;R�a�H@�hm�}n#>�m�n��y��Be��V;[��^���M�U�S���
��~��c��ދ��I2�f��0aWQeY�Y��H�?f�5jK�����m�G���2�j��-��ߥ�-"p�/牤Eۼa��^O�I��(���f����&�V�)h�S�E'Y�Ep�mh���f�v{%��Y�]i��Ri\��]:�e�7&rnx�������^0ÿ7!��o?�qˋIbv`HqᢖCr3�6�d�7��cNdF]�Iꑈ���K!��˗�:�dO9�[v+F��e����,j�k��.�w�[m��J0�q�O0���~�
L���L��&�n���y>0A''dPL�(zW���j����Z,�Q��NQ�g�Y�q����)���    �<s�f�u��|-I�s�it�nQ��ܙɹ�O3S��.Wqx��܆W%��Fa�.-%�ف!ǆ�YD!����ٓ��Z���9�vU'�F"t2�b9,�^lK._�����<��mح����c�T����'���@  
S`T�cl�l
�cm���U���6�*��=�@8۶�$�����_��(�eBۿ������ܞ�h(�� I&��ڂ�wo;��?�8��S-ec�)������B�c�a�����T��uc�a�h�������CT|�
(l�w�"ua�ڵ&e��x���6 �����c��I��C���r��]M��.b�^s3?\�Ϛ������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������v�$��4�+�TE��Cw��]cvޕ���M����)$�_{PT���{=G�q�@�
`���t#�e ���V�hZLtL ��Ta�t�.�a�R�V��<�
�s�ӶY"�j��!E
�N��N�8;V���|�կ�����8�wBSi?W�u9�V��K�����]���nfg�9�\y�n�#�&�!H�m.�*.�p��%K�[�i�{&
w9�>�Q ����r �oRJ�(tk��\i�B�Y0�f������(x��E�*�cUǙ��FzV���z!���L����h]�?6�]�������a��EW��T�S�wl�ܹ���6/�F�$VZ�F�3�EcݾmR@:�?�Kn���ﾊ�k^�߾q�Ǽ
���v�q71
F[ivIQp
@����9*_��O��0k��i���d����x"�V���C�cX8�m:�M��jɀ�\K6_�/�Q@�;Ǭ�/��P���<�]�xr3ҵ4γ�MG]�e�X��x΋B�!��z�h����d��3��*���ژ�8+��g.�ͅw�}�6�"�Ղ5�b+��j���
[t�|g}�V�Z����f=�o����@     $_�kX{lË��km�=�S��
�g�*u�a�$��n4�i)1�>���  �H  C�F�N��$ѓ�v!�����sM�����:�75�_2ܨ�������O]hnj:����,b�dޑ�J���-�f*Ut�\�+\O �@��1���Kʇ�EԬN�Q����$��h8�kVy㷤�#W'B��1�Ty�5i-l���9r��a[�})& ��EC��c�A����Pww�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������II��I���C3��,��j�9�l���b@�0�b�Μ�1D�]��<��s]E�-ʍ.�>n�m޴�ֆ棩i}��)vM�Ĩ�nۢ�6b�WJ������  �q�J$�a�{d]J���A�q!��IH����Ƶg�;zI�5rt*ICL�G��V���Κ����)���JgҒb!�$T=l�;$>�=�wq$�Rn$�i9   Q�Ogh�4l���n��3@�J\���q�7^+�\�i2}�i��U��V�&h�e.䵰5�$t���[�Y���T�E5&�g�_��$�X�o]�O�n4�0
Z�۸���4�g�b}���Sw%vNLØ�S�c�W��BᏐ���@�Չ+��^�u�r�h�>���j1��������+����SOq���8����훗�IM����RD�IL��I��r��8����hٙ���
df���S.$�)^n0�W̹��d���O����L<Ѭ�]�k`knH(�akh�(�!a6�Z,�jM��~�s�I���޻��H�h3Z`8��i�q�'�i��l��?���J윙�1������5�҅�!I^��V7��2��J&����}oÐ�cߩ��7M[�W-syb�2���U��q-1�?)�7/j��u��ؤ�l���@    YT�x{l�k*�om�amU�c
�l-���a����j��vxX.�0X{L�bew[��BM��� ��z�L�1�ڷ,&�_�S����-���1:d�"C�iG���Xp������~Y�o8
��c�Qf7Sc8r�u�dm2K�Q� �Bի�@�����L�|���v����xk��N�a�4�H�e�Q��=�pu�'��lT4ѓ0�n�oL�ć    ��X��
͠q�!��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������7�][n��F�/c �lL��+|���I��`�`^U�F6{V��k�
�V;%�x�y�'L��H{
(�k���1���o�=
��Y�q�!��l`�Pa����Ij1��Z�x����<V�����N��Qp���
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android studio cannot play media files, so it opened the file as a text file. After all every files contains data in the form of bytes. If you open your media file with any other text editors, you'll see the same result.

If you open any other media files from Android studio, you'll get the similar result. So this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you... but how do you get them to play media?